# Unable to upgrade php-common because is about to remove libapache2-mod-php5.6

Tags: debian, apt

I am in the process of upgrading from Debian 11 to Debian 12.

I have completed 99% of the work, but now I am encountering the following issue:

```
# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libapache2-mod-php5.6 php-pear php5.6-cli php5.6-common php5.6-curl php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-json php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-opcache php5.6-readline php5.6-xml
  php5.6-xsl php5.6-zip php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-json php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline php7.0-xml
The following packages will be upgraded:
  php-common
```

To upgrade `php-common`, Debian will remove `libapache2-mod-php5.6`.

I (think I) can of course reinstall all `php5.6-*` packages later.

But I'm not so sure I can reinstall `libapache2-mod-php5.6`

How can I complete the upgrade in this situation?

Comment: Debian 12 uses PHP 8 by default. You will not get 5.6 from the regular repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This time i resolved by myself

I added the good `sury` repository for php packages

```
wget -qO /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg 

echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list

apt-get update
```

Then I can complete `dist-upgrade` because this repo is serving these old packages

Comment: PHP 5.6 has reached EOL [four and a half years ago](https://www.php.net/eol.php). You should _seriously_ consider migrating to a newer version.

Comment: I know. But I cannot change policy of my company. sad, but real. At least, I can still upgrade "my" vps to latest debian